# PHP unexpected results - Always returns true

Tags: php, function

Hi I started following and then adapting Adam Khoury's videos on creating a social media network. The code I have always seems to return the value true for a users login status, even having deleted all cookies etc.

I have left Adam's code pretty much untouched, renamed a couple of variables I believe, and then created my own function to call the functions and handle the data returned. I assume I've messed up in how the functions share information with each other, but not sure where or what to do to rectify it.

Any help to keep me headed the right direction would be great.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("includes/db_conx.php");

$login_status;
$logged_user = "";

//  Create globally accessable variables to store username and login status
function dataCheck() {
checkSession();
global $login_status, $logged_user;

if (checkSession() === false) {
    $login_status = "false";
    $logged_user = "";
} else {
    $login_status = "true";
    $logged_user = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
}
}

// User Verify function
function evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p){
     $sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE userID='$id' AND username='$u' AND password='$p' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
     $query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
     $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
     if($numrows > 0){
         return true;
    }
} 

function checkSession() {
    global $db_conx;

    // Checks to see if the user is already logged in and a session has been created
    if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
        $log_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION['userid']);
        $log_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
        $log_password = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['password']);

        // Verify the user
        $global_verified = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
    } else {
        // Check for recent cookie data
        checkCookies();
    }
}

function checkCookies() {
global $user_verified;
    // Checks to see if the user has visited the site recently and has details logged in cookies
    if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])){
        $_SESSION['userid'] = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_COOKIE['id']);
        $_SESSION['username'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_]#i', '', $_COOKIE['user']);
        $_SESSION['password'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['pass']);

        $log_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
        $log_username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $log_password = $_SESSION['password'];

        // Verify the user
        $global_verified = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);

        if($global_verified == true){
            // Update their lastlogin datetime field
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET lastlogin=now() WHERE userID='$log_id' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to review.... check your error log to find where the problem can be

Comment: I notice two different DB connection variables. `$conx` and `$db_conx`

Comment: Storing the password in `$_COOKIE`?? Bad idea bro… Besides, what's with all those global variables and stuff? Do yourself a favor and use a modern framework… ;-)

Comment: checkCookies() returns nothing except false. And the `global $user_verified` is never userd.

Comment: Also you have 4 functions, but you never call one of them from outside the functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to test a login script without a logout script. Once the script's logged you in the data is saved to session, at that point your `checkSession()` will always return true until your session times out or you write a log out script. The following code will log you out so you can try logging in again:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

As both of the other answered suggested, you're also missing a return value in `checkSession()`, but I suspect you should do it something like this instead of the above suggestion:

```
function checkSession() {
    global $db_conx;

    // Checks to see if the user is already logged in and a session has been created
    if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
        $log_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION['userid']);
        $log_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
        $log_password = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['password']);

        // Verify the user
        $global_verified = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
    } else {
        // Check for recent cookie data
        $global_verified = checkCookies();
    }
    return $global_verified;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something in your checkSession() function...

```
if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
    $log_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION['userid']);
    $log_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
    $log_password = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['password']);

    // Verify the user
    $global_verified = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
    return true;
} else {
    // Check for recent cookie data
    checkCookies();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`checkSession()` doesn't return anything. This means the `checkSession() === false` check will always fail.

There's numerous security issues with your code as noted in the comments, I would look into fixing them.